# Layout Changes when I Try to Print

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I have an inherited document. It has been cleaned up the best I can. I have previously printed it to PDF with some fuss but successfully.

Now, after it went out for review (on OneDrive Share), whenever I try to print all the pages turn to landscape. How do I fix my problems?

Comment: Can you repair the original document in the appropriate Office Tool?  Make a backup first.  Then use Adobe Acrobat to create a PDF and then see if it prints properly.

Comment: What type of document? Have you tried repair? How complex is the document? Can it be recreated?

Comment: You can create a new word document, copy the content into it, and print it as a PDF.

Comment: So this is a huge 350-page document with complex formatting. multiple sections and very specific requirements. I do have tables in layout format in their own section later in the document. It can't just be copied over, and anyway, that would probably bring the problem with it. Repair messes it up. So I ended up having to revert to an older version and do all the edits again; tedious!I have tried very hard to find this problem; elsewhere and have not found it so it's obviously not common (or my search terms are all wrong).